# Lenovo Twist wireless driver n/a

Tags: 20.04, wireless, lenovo

I have a curious problem finding similar issues to mine are not quite the same.  Currently on my bench is a Lenovo Twist Model 334776U.  I imaged the 2in1 using our clonezilla image of Xubuntu 20.04.  Initially the touch pad and ptr-stick did not work. Wireless sometimes did (it iirc drop connection).  However, through some 'googling' (the link I forget) it was mentioned that this issue was resolved with Kernel 5.19.  I went to install that kernel (using the Ubuntu mainline kernel app) but no further 5 series versions of the kernels were listed.  So, I installed the 6.0.5 version, booted into that kernel and ran updates.  Now when I boot up the 6+ kernel loads. The touch pad and ptr stick may or may not work, but wireless definitely does not work.  I am currently not near the machine. It is at work and we are not open on weekends.  Below, I have assembled data from this machine:

```
~$ lspci -vnn | grep -A8 03:00.0

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:0607]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f1d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting

~$ rfkill list

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

~$ inxi -Fzxx
System:    Kernel: 6.0.5-060005-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.13 wm: xfwm4 
           dm: LightDM Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 334776U v: ThinkPad Twist serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 334776U v: Win8 Pro DPK TPG serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: GDETC1WW (1.81 ) 
           date: 06/27/2019 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 21.0 Wh condition: 21.0/47.1 Wh (45%) volts: 16.1/14.8 model: SONY 45N1169 
           serial: <filter> status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-3337U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Ivy Bridge rev: 9 
           L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 14366 
           Speed: 950 MHz min/max: 800/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1290 2: 945 3: 929 4: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:0166 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) 
           v: 4.2 Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-e8fc5cc 2022-06-22 focal-oibaf-ppa) direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:1e20 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k6.0.5-060005-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n driver: N/A port: efa0 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           chip ID: 14e4:4359 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 2000 bus ID: 04:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 298.09 GiB used: 24.65 GiB (8.3%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Hitachi model: HTS723232A7A364 size: 298.09 GiB speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 292.85 GiB used: 24.65 GiB (8.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 fan-2: 0 
Info:      Processes: 186 Uptime: 52m Memory: 3.41 GiB used: 691.1 MiB (19.8%) Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 
           Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 alt: 7/9 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 running in: xfce4-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

Modules loaded:

```
~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 86016  16
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     81920  1
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   163840  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
i915                 3162112  6
drm_buddy              20480  1 i915
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
ttm                    98304  1 i915
intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr
drm_display_helper    184320  1 i915
cec                    81920  2 drm_display_helper,i915
btusb                  61440  0
rc_core                65536  1 cec
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
drm_kms_helper        200704  2 drm_display_helper,i915
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btintel                45056  1 btusb
thinkpad_acpi         139264  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
hid_sensor_rotation    20480  0
hid_sensor_incl_3d     20480  0
intel_powerclamp       24576  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
hid_sensor_als         20480  1
hid_sensor_magn_3d     20480  1
hid_sensor_accel_3d    20480  1
mei_hdcp               24576  0
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     20480  0
mei_pxp                20480  0
platform_profile       16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
bluetooth             876544  42 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
uvcvideo              122880  0
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    40960  1 ecdh_generic
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
hid_sensor_trigger     20480  12 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
sysimgblt              20480  1 drm_kms_helper
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  1 hid_sensor_trigger
coretemp               24576  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
hid_sensor_iio_common    28672  7 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  1 snd_hda_intel
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,thinkpad_acpi
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       81920  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
kvm_intel             425984  0
videodev              274432  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
kvm                  1142784  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec         172032  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
industrialio          106496  12 industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_incl_3d,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
snd_hda_core          118784  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
mc                     69632  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
hid_multitouch         32768  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
polyval_clmulni        16384  0
polyval_generic        16384  1 polyval_clmulni
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           393216  4
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                77824  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm               159744  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
rapl                   20480  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
mei_me                 49152  2
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                   114688  19 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
mei                   139264  5 mei_hdcp,mei_pxp,mei_me
think_lmi              36864  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
firmware_attributes_class    16384  1 think_lmi
soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd
joydev                 32768  0
input_leds             16384  0
soc_button_array       20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
binfmt_misc            24576  1
sch_fq_codel           24576  2
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     28672  0
parport                73728  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
pstore_blk             16384  0
ramoops                28672  0
reed_solomon           28672  1 ramoops
pstore_zone            32768  1 pstore_blk
efi_pstore             16384  0
drm                   585728  9 drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,drm_buddy,thinkpad_acpi,i915,ttm
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               57344  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_sensor_custom      28672  0
hid_sensor_hub         28672  9 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 65536  0
hid                   159744  4 usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,hid_generic
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         36864  0
psmouse               184320  0
r8169                 102400  0
rtsx_pci              106496  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
ahci                   49152  1
realtek                32768  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
libahci                49152  1 ahci
i2c_i801               36864  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
xhci_pci               24576  0
lpc_ich                28672  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
wmi                    32768  2 wmi_bmof,think_lmi
video                  61440  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
```

If you've gotten this far, thank you for taking time for me.  Currently, if possible, I would like to get the wireless working.  The Touch pad and ptr-stick are of course important,  But one step at a time.

Regards

Can I get a BUMP?

Comment: You have a few misspelled words that I can not guess what they are. This might affect the question. It might be an idea to correct them.

Comment: Hi @David what specifically are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: This may work, but it looks like `b43` is blacklisted.

Comment: I have a laptop with same pci device. Tested on ubuntu 22.04 , and works just fine.

Comment: Yes, it should work if it is not blacklisted by `bcmwl-kernel-source` or another way.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answers.  I will have to find this machine again and check it out.  My company has moved and lots of machines have gotten misplaced. I'll have to dig it out :).